# Protobuf to parse pre-allocated data and output without copy

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, c++20

I'm studying for adopting Protobuf in my Embedded IoT framework, wherein a message can be received from network sources as MQTT/HTTP/etc and being fed to the system.

I seek to fully process the incoming data without copying it, so the intended use is to feed protobuf with the starting address `std::uint8_t*` and size.

And with a basic schema of message being:

```
message Message {
    optional string str = 1;
    optinal bytes raw = 2;
}
```

The intended output of array data (strings and raw data) would be `std::string_view` and `std::span` respectively*, which would point to the received data.

So to avoid unnecessary copies, is that applicable? and if so, how?

* Any pair of `std::uint8_t*` and `size_t` points to the relevant data is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with Google's C++ protobuf library using the existing message structures. It is possible to use the lower level functions to parse field-by-field, but then you don't have the benefit of code autogenerated from proto files.

It seems like it should be possible with [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/), though I haven't tried this specifically. By default, nanopb will generate a callback or a static array for strings, but this can be overridden with generator options.

For your example, a `myproto.options` file would contain:

```
*         include:"span"
msg.raw   callback_datatype:"std::span<uint8_t>", callback_function="bytes_to_span"
```

and you would provide the named callback function for conversion:

```
bool bytes_to_span(pb_istream_t *istream, pb_ostream_t *ostream, const pb_field_iter_t *field)
{
    if (istream)
    {
        // Copy pointer to field contents in input stream into a std::span in message structure.
        auto result = static_cast<std::span<uint8_t>*>(field->pData);
        *result = std::span<uint8_t>(istream->state, istream->bytes_left);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: C++ Protobuf offer `ZeroCopyInputStream` and `ZeroCopyOutputStream`, wont these help?

Comment: I've came across other serializers as "FlatBuffers" and "CAP'n Proto". What do you think regarding these?

Comment: Per the provided solution, I think there's really no problem just to receive both pointer and length of the expected string/bytes.

Comment: ZeroCopyInput/OutputStream just avoid extra copy between destination buffer and some other storage. Flatbuffers and cap'n proto are altogether different formats and too much to explain here.

Comment: So in the worst case I would have one copy by utilizing ZeroCopyInput/Output??

Comment: You may take a look for the concerned question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963115/serialization-scheme-protobuf-capn-proto-flatbuffers-to-adopt-for-a-system).